# Best approach for comparing 2 XML files (Before & After) for specific changes?

Tags: xml

I have a Database that I update on a weekly basis that creates XML files that I would like to compare after making changes.

The database is set up with 150 Pages which each contain 50 tables. 
These tables contain an identifier which is sometimes moved to different tables or different pages, or removed all together.

I'm hoping to find a way to compare the 2 XML files from before I make my changes and after and identify

when an ID moved from one page, table to another
when an ID is changed 
when an ID is removed
or when other attributes for the table are changed

and output the changes to a file or a SQL database

For Example:
Page 3, Table 2 was changed from ID 3452 to ID 2316
Page 3, Table 7 was moved to Page 3, Table 1
Page 3, Table 8 was deleted

I'm guessing I need a way to query each page, table coordinate for changes.

I've been hunting google all afternoon but I'm not really sure how to phrase what I am looking for and I think it may be hindering my search attempts.

Answer (score 0):

if you are manually comparing the xml, you can check out [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).